# How to maje a rotation but save the side of a gameObject in place in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

if I make a rotation on a gameObject in unity it makes a rotation and save the center of the gameobject in place and change the position of the sides. I want to make a rotation that saves one pisition of size and change the position of the cneter and the other side relatively.
For example if I make a long stick gameObject I want it will rotate but one side will be in place. How do I do this?

I dont know what to try

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are asking for is to be able to rotate an object respect to another point/axis that its not itself.
For that you can set an empty object in the position where you whant the pivot point, make your object child of that empty pivot, and rotate the parent. The child will rotate with the parent and respect to it ( respect to its position and its axis).

[image]